# Centering A Horizontal Aligned Header

Tags: html, css, css-float, center

I have three divs I would like to center horizontally in the header of the page like so:

(nav Logo nav)

html:

```
<header class="header">
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="navleft">
        <li class="navleft-item">Item</li>
        <li class="navleft-item">Item</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt=""/> 
    </div>
    <ul class="navright">
        <li class="navright-item">Item</li>
        <li class="navright-item">Item</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

css:

```
.nav {
}

.logo {
}

.navleft {
}

.navright {
}

.navleft-item {
display: inline;
}

.navright-item {
display: inline;
}
```

CSS is bare because I erased half of it due to sheer frustration.

Floating left all the divs doesn't work and when I use display inline-block I can't move navleft and navright up to align it with the logo. At this point I have no idea.

Comment: Please share your `css` also OR create a jsfiddle. Thanks.

Comment: I added CSS even though there isn't much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `text-align: center` and `display: inline-block`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLFPL/)

**OR**

You can use `display: table` + `table-cell`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLFPL/1/)

```
.nav {    
    text-align: center;
}
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navleft {
     display: inline-block;
}
.navright {
     display: inline-block;
}
.navleft-item {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navright-item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: It works but I cannot move navleft and navright up to align to the center of the logo. The navs stay locked to the bottom of the logo and even vertical-align:middle won't work. @JunM

Comment: @user3232801 - Please see updated answer or this link - http://jsfiddle.net/YLFPL/1/

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.navleft {float: left;}
.navright {float: right;}
.logo {text-align: center;}
</style>
```